# Передача значение переменной

Tags: java, android

Есть класс

```
@InjectViewState
public class AuthFPresenter extends MvpPresenter<AuthFView> {

private Socket socket;
private Context context;

public AuthFPresenter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    socket = SocketSingleton.getInstance();
}

public void sendEmail(String email) {
    //send
}

@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
public void waitForResponse() {
    //answerFromSever (async)
    parseData(data)
}

private void parseData(JSONObject data) {
    send(email)
}

}
```

Куда я сначала передаю почту в метод sendEmail, а потом получаю асинхронный ответ от сервера, где я должен отправить этот email дальше, но так как метод асинхронный я не могу передавать этот email между методами.

Была идея делать через поле класса, но мне кажется это не лучший вариант. 
Можете ли вы предложить какую-нибудь идею?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: проблема в том, что answerFromSever (async) асинхронен, поэтому parseData вызывается раньше, чем надо?

Comment: @Maxgmer время его запуска точно узнать нельзя. И метод waitForResponse запускается тогда, когда сервер решит. Так что передать туда невозможно